# Get Specific Recycling Time For IIS With PowerShell

Tags: powershell, iis, time, recycle

I'm trying to find the specific time that my app pool is set to recycle on my server using PowerShell.  I know it's set to recycle at 1 AM daily on the test server that I'm looking at.  I'm running:

```
Get-ItemProperty -Path IIS:\AppPools\AppPool -Name recycling.periodicRestart.time
```

and the value that's showing is 00:00:00

For testing purposes, I attempted to run:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path IIS:\AppPools\AppPool -Name recycling.periodicRestart.time -Value 3.00:00:00
```

I checked to see how this changed.  The "Specific Time(s)" field still reads 1:00 AM, but now the "Regular Time Intervals (in minutes)" is set to 4320 minutes.  So apparently I'm looking at the wrong value... Any idea how I can see the value in the "Specific Time" field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path IIS:\AppPools\DefaultAppPool -Name recycling.periodicRestart.schedule -Value @{value = '03:00:00'}
```

Get it with:

```
Get-ItemProperty -Path IIS:\AppPools\DefaultAppPool -Name recycling.periodicRestart.schedule.collection
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not trying to change it, I just want to audit it to see what it is...

Comment: For what it's worth, I've also tried:

    Get-itemproperty -Path IIS:\AppPools\WebPage -Name recycling.periodicRestart.schedule

And saw nothing that resembled what I was looking for.

Comment: Just add .collection, ifs an array of values.